# How the compiler generate this unexpected results during multiple increment in same line

Tags: c++, increment

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a =3;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d",++a,--a,a++,++a,++a);
}
```

It prints the result -

> 4 4 3 4 4

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: The order of evaluation of arguments to a function is unspecified. There are 120 possible ways that the code could evaluate those arguments, and no basis for expecting any one of them.

Comment: Despite the linked answer in the close votes, the behavior here is not undefined. It is unspecified; the code is valid, but the compiler is free to evaluate the five arguments in any order.

Comment: It’s undefined behaviour. There is no sequence point between evaluation of arguments. Actually, the compiler is free to mix evaluations if the arguments.